# Remove power / shutdown button from Cinnamon menu for standard users

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I would like to prevent my children from powering off our Linux Mint 19 desktop pc. I have them set-up as standard users. I would like them to log off but not shutdown. I can't find where to set this just for standard users or on each user account.

Comment: With a lack of an answer here I've raised a feature request. https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/8566

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to limit this change to only standard users but you can remove the shutdown button by removing it from the source code in the applet.js file at `/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/menu@cinnamon.org/applet.js`. something similar to what was suggested [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/making-changes-in-the-main-menu-4175692865/)

Comment: Thanks for answering this very old question (2019). I no longer use Cinnamon so will have to leave it to others to test this.